# Symfony accessing custom propel query

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1, propel

I am trying to do what I thought would be a trivial task using Symfony 1.4 with the propel ORM. I've got a custom static class setup that I would like to use to return the id of a row by searching the name of the item.

Here's my function:

```
static public function getItemIdByName ( $name )
{
    $criteria = new Criteria();
    $criteria-> clearSelectColumns();
    $criteria -> add (ItemsPeer::ITEM_NAME, $name, Criteria::LIKE );
    $criteria -> addSelectColumn(ItemsPeer::ITEM_ID);
    $criteria -> setLimit (1);

    $itemID = ItemsPeer::doSelect( $criteria );

    return $itemID;
}
```

Now when I return $itemID, I get the name of the item. However, I cannot get the item_id column at all. I've tried returning $itemID[1] and several other column indexes, but it says those do not exist. If I print_r($itemID), I see an array of every column in that table, the only two with values are item_id and item_name. However, I still can't find a way to return or access that variable.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the error is in position of `clearSelectColumns`, but I can mistaken. Try to use doSelectStmt instead of doSelect:

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->add(ItemsPeer::ITEM_NAME, $name, Criteria::LIKE);
$c->clearSelectColumns();
$c->addSelectColumn(ItemsPeer::ITEM_ID);
$c->setLimit(1);

$stmt = ItemsPeer::doSelectStmt($c);
return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN); // $itemID
```

This should solve your problems. However, if you are using sf 1.4 and Propel >= 1.5, I'd suggest you to use Propel Query:

```
return ItemsQuery::create()
  ->filterByItemName($name . '%')
  ->select('ItemId')
  ->findOne();
```